# C# ToolTip Display Duration

Tags: c#, tooltip

i need some advise on tooltip behaviour.

i have tested the following:

```
gameFormToolTip.Show("hello", HomeTableLayoutPanel, 30000);

gameFormToolTip.SetToolTip(HomeTableLayoutPanel, GameModel.alphaCoords(HomeTableLayoutPanel.GetCellPosition(nowPicStrl).Column) + "," + HomeTableLayoutPanel.GetCellPosition(nowPicStrl).Row);
```

but in both cases the tooltip displays only for few fractions of a second. i have tried changing autopopdelay also and the behaviour stays the same!

am i missing something here? how can i make the tooltip stay on for longer?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should set ToolTip.AutomaticDelay property (value in milliseconds) otherwise tooltip will display only for 500ms.